# Transfer Matrix Method in 3D (optics)

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, maxwell-equations

Recently I came across a nice way to analytically calculate the absorption of light in a multilayer material, see the following Wikipedia article 
:-  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer-matrix_method_%28optics%29?wprov=sfla1

I must admit I don't know too much about electromagnetics and I don't have a deep understanding of the Transfer Matrix Method (TMM) so I'd like to apologize in advance in case  my question is stupid.

So far I've only found descriptions of the TMM in 1 dimension and I was wondering if it is extendable to 3D? Or is there a better way to handle the 3D case?